# How long do I need to stay in Vietnam when doing a visa run from Cambodia for a baby?

Tags: borders, vietnam, cambodia, visa-runs

I have a newborn in Cambodia and finally got to the point where I have a Lithuanian passport with Cambodian exit visa stamped in, valid for 7 days. I will need to leave the country with the baby and then come back and get him an E class visa upon entry, which then can be extended forever. I spoke about this yesterday at the immigration department and they seemed to be ok with the plan below. However from my personal experience I know that things at the border don't always run so smooth...

This one is tricky, as normally no one does visa runs in Cambodia since you can get indefinitely extendable E class visas. Still it is worth asking (and I have a slight Asian border-crossing phobia). I am planning to cross the Vietnamese border with the baby, while his mom will wait at the border to save on Vietnamese visa. Also, her Cambodian visa is 3 month single-entry. Then I get Vietnamese visas for me and the baby and then head ASAP back (baby is 3.5 months old and he has boob addiction. I have a bottle of formula, but he doesn't like it much. Also he hasn't been away from mom more than 10 feet ever). When doing visa runs is it wise to stay for some time in Vietnam, or can I cross immediately back and no one is going to blink an eye?

**How long do I need to stay in Vietnam when doing a visa run from Cambodia for a baby to be on the safe side?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I did the journey to Vietnam and back and you do not need to spend any time at all inside Vietnam.

Officer at the Vietnam side stamped both entry and exit stamps at the same time after I told him that I am doing a visa run for my baby. He then told me to turnaround and head back to Cambodian side without any checks being done second time.

All and all procedure was mostly painless and took around 45 minutes.